# Debian packages without GUI install

Tags: debian, package-management, gnome, x86

I am installing Debian on an (old) Atom chip, i386 Kernel, and choose not to proceed with any GUI. Meanwhile, I see Gnome packages being installed. Is this normal? Why?

Comment: Don't know. What packages are being installed?

Comment: I don't know either. During install screen, they go too fast. Is it expected to have any Gnome package in a terminal-only install?

Comment: Only you know what you asked to be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

You can get a full list of installed packages with e.g. `dpkg --get-selections | less`.

If you selected to install a tool that has both text-based and GUI interface, it may have dependencies to some X11 and/or GNOME libraries. That is usually pretty harmless.

Also, with X11, it is perfectly possible to run a system with no display and no GPU at all, and still have GUI applications running on that system and sending their output to a remote display on some other system. That's why "no local GUI" does not necessarily mean "no GUI applications installed at all".

Comment: Nice point, and thank you for clarifying. I believe I saw gnome package names quickly passing through the install status, but then when finished, they have actually been ignored for the TTY-only Debian.